# how to read .OSM file & plot on map OFFLINE

Tags: android, dictionary, offline

i am new to .OSM file.
I want to plot latitude and longitude from the **.OSM** file on the map but it should be OFFLINE.
I do not want to download map images or else in short i don't want to use **INTERNET**

as the **.OSM** file in XML format so we can get the latitude and longitude easily from that but the main thing is how to plot it on map in offline mode.

i had searched on this & i just found that to store the images of the map(Visited area) to sdcard for the first time & other times just fetched the data from the sdcard & show the Images..

but i want to do it **TOTALLY** *OFFLINE*

Thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about OpenStreetMap you should better ask your question at the [OpenStreetMap Help Forum](http://help.openstreetmap.org/).

Comment: The OpenStreetMap Wiki has a large [list of Android applications](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android#Map_display_features) capable of displaying a map, offline and online.